# How can I test all ocpp 1.6 operations?

Tags: ocpp

I developed ev charger. How can I test all ocpp 1.6 operations? Json format only.

I tried different search systems

Answer (score 0):

To test the Charging station/Charger you must have a CSMS(Charging system management system) for you can have below ways,

- Build your CSMS
- Take part in plugfest testing
- Find CSMS near you and connect and do test

Assumption is the CSMS must support the 1.6 Charger and have implemented OCPP 1.6 CSMS messages both CS->CSMS and CSMS->CS

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SteVe](https://github.com/steve-community/steve) to simulate a CSMS (Charging Station Management System).

It comes with most OCPP 1.6J (JSON) profiles, messages and keys pre-built in.
You just need to register the Serial Number of your charger, which in SteVe is called Chargebox ID (*or Chargepoint ID*) and then, if your charger is connected correctly to the server, you can start to send/receive OCPP messages.